# Negative margin gives scroll

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve paddings everywhere except sides of content. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3tbovz0f/1/

CSS:

```
.col1 .fill {
    background: red;
}
.col2 .fill {
    background: blue;
}
.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.pd {
    padding: 10px;
}
.row {
    margin: -10px;
}
.fill {
    height: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col1">
        <div class="pd">
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2">
        <div class="pd">
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get scrollbar from this. What do I do wrong? Why it appears?

Comment: You might try supplying an image of what this is supposed to look like. I think there is some confusion.

Comment: I'm confused.. why not just do something like padding: 10px 0;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `box-sizing:border-box` for it to appear properly.

Here's a fiddle of it working properly: http://jsfiddle.net/sLxphrke/14/

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.col1 .fill {
    background: red;
}
.col2 .fill {
    background: blue;
}
.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-left:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.pd {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.row {
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: pink;
}
```

I also changed the padding on PD to only affect the top and bottom and gave each column their own 10px padding. To create more rows all you would have to do is change the 50% to 100/NumberOfRows, like 33.3333% for 3 rows. Everything else will stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

Negative margins will pull the div off the page, thus giving you the scroll-bar, negative margins are not good practice and should be avoided. You also are adding padding to two 50% width elements which will make it larger than 100%.
If you want to do this then you will have to use box-sizing border box.

I restructured your css a little bit and I think you were asking to have padding on everything but the outer sides? So I structured the padding to do this.

js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3tbovz0f/11/

```
/*makes it so you don't have to calculate exact percentage*/
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    margin: 0;  
}
.col1 .fill {
    background: red;
}
.col2 .fill {
    background: blue;
}
.col1 {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.col2 {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.row {
    width:100%;
}
.fill {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle didn't work, it still has padding on the sides. Don't think you posted the right link

Comment: My apologies! The correct link is there now and if you aren't using a reset the body automatically adds margin so I added that in as well.

Answer (score 0):

update with this.
check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/sLxphrke/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.row {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I think this will work. And your scroll will be removed.

Comment: What I missed out? Before given negative point. First try to elaborate properly. Otherwise you will feel the same.

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve his basic problem, He wants no space on the side of the colored divs. They are supposed to be flush to the side of the window. http://jsfiddle.net/3tbovz0f/4/

Comment: check my fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/sLxphrke/ I have used the same code. And it works without even margin-10px. Using negative margin is not the best approach.

Comment: See... the red and blue divs are *not* flush up against the edge of the window. There should be no pink (in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLxphrke/1/) ) on the left and right side. That is what he is trying to do.

Comment: But Paul. Just to confirm you what ever your code describes is not upto the standards. My strategy is same but without using negative margins. If he will use negative margin. He will surely face problem in future design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the mother `.row` div was not fulfilling the entire screen(specifically) and you had 2 other child divs with 50% each. So, when you summed both is 100% + the margins/padings, that was giving you more than 100%. So you had to specify the width of the mother div so that the child divs be relative to its mother.  You just had to add `width:100%` to `.row` class .... I just created new fiddle check out: `http://jsfiddle.net/3tbovz0f/3/`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question **[which it doesn't really]**.....[**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Ok, valid your comment, Its just I saw it so simple that I didn't even explained it. I've just updated my answer with the explanation. I will take that into consideration for all future answers. Thanks.